# Jacoco instrumentation using tcp server method

Tags: java, jacoco, tcpserver

I am trying to run integration tests on my java code from remote server, so whenever my tests hit my code server, jacoco records it.

I am new to jacoco, till now i have gather that there is tcp server method which doesnot require any restart.

1. I have added below line in my /etc/profile.

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-javaagent:/home/vansh/jacoco/lib/jacocoagent.jar=address=*,port=57026,destfile=/home/vansh/jacoco/jacoco.exec,output=tcpserver"
```

2)but when i am trying to take dump using below command -

```
java -jar jacococli.jar dump --address localhost --port  57026 --destfile /home/vansh/jacoco/jacoco-it.exec
```

```
ERROR:

[INFO] Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:57026.
[WARN] Connection refused (Connection refused).
[INFO] Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:57026.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
```

I checked that there is nothing run on port 57026, is my first command javaagent one is correct?

Answer (score 2):

I have done same thing a year ago, In my case I run a TCP_Client jar for collecting the dump with many ways(periodically/with and without resetting previous coverage).

I set JAVA_OPTS as follows,

```
-javaagent:<file_Path_for_jacoco_agent>/jacocoagent.jar=output=tcpserver,address=*,port=6300
```

Here is my repo link of tcp client - [enter link description here](https://github.com/Wageesha95/TCP_Client_JacocoCC)

set fixed arguments to the code or create a jar with this repo

If you are running a jar from this code,

You can run this jar with passing "address" "port" "dump-folder-path" "periodic-time-for-dumping" "resetting-option-with-every-dump"  arguments.

example : `java -jar ExecutedDataDump.jar "127.0.0.1" "6300" "D:\\server-dumplog\\" "5" "noreset"`

You will get get jacoco.exec files with time stamp in every 5 secs time and due to noreset every jacoco.exec is get cumulative report

Hope this will helpful for you.