# JaCoCo agent multiple JVMs same destination file

Tags: java, jacoco

I couldn't find anything in the documentation which could answer my question.

If I have 2 services (JVMs) running **simultaneously** on the same host, can they use the same JaCoCo destination file? E.g.: can I have these arguments for both of them?

```
-javaagent:/opt/coverage/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/opt/coverage/jacoco.exec
```

Or the append mode does not work concurrently and I must specify different destination files?

Comment: You question is over using Jacoco not integrated (in maven for example) while surefire executes? You want code coverage to check live running code?

Comment: Exactly. I'd like to instrument e2e testing.

Comment: I guess that you have to have one file per VM, and in the end aggregate the results (like in a multi module project when running Unit Tests). It appear to exist another option that is running the agent as TCP, but I've never try that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081697/jacoco-instrumentation-using-tcp-server-method.